# Problem Installing Ubuntu 11.04 on Dell Inspiron 1545

Tags: installation, 11.04

I had windows 7 installed on my system ( not the genuine copy ), somehow it caught up into the windows update and then it started causing problem. I had ubuntu installed inside Windows at that time. (using wubi)

I "System Restored" my windows a couple of times and it seemed to be working fine for some time. But then one time, it did not boot at all, though if i Log into Ubuntu it would work for me.

I gave the laptop repair for windows reinstallation and they told me that i had some problem with my hard disk, which i doubt since i can log into my ubuntu installed. I tried to format everything and have just the Ubuntu installed on my system. (11.04).

I make my pen drive bootable and try to install it. (UnetBootin)

But i just cant seem to get it working, initially it would ask me to install ubuntu and when i would confirm it, it would carry on with the installation but then would get stuck somehow, now it just asks me if i want to install ubuntu , and if i click on yes, it wont even start the installation.

I go to the help option (in the menu ) and here is what i get.

```
  ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
  ata3.00: error: { UNC }
```

Now what is the problem, has my hard disk really crashed, does it need entire replacement (I HOPE NOT), or is there something i can do.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you hard disk is bad.  Try to get a backup if possible.

Comment: Any reason for using an older version of Ubuntu? Try ``12.04.1`` when running from your pendrive. And then check with 'Disk Utility' (palimpsest) to see what the diagnostics (SMART) tell you.

Comment: @gertvdijk that's the only version i have got available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry that I don't have extra time at the moment to look this up in more detail for you. However what I believe you are looking at here is a **master boot record that is failing**. *Nix and Windows uses these first sectors differently on a hard drive and when that first inner area of the disk begins failing, Windows is going to be the first one to start having problems.

I have managed to get a few more weeks of life (sometimes a three or four months) out of **repairing a MBR**, but really that HD is "on the way out". Also note that if you replace the hard drive it is often possible to use the older one for data storage even though the MBR is having problems, it is not entirely uncommon for the other parts of the disk to be ok. Just make sure to keep good backups :-)

Comment: Backup is not the problem, anythign i can do to delay the crash, not in a position to actually replace the entire hard disk. Thanks anyway for the help.